# What if someone wishes to not become a magical girl in Madoka Magica?

Tags: madoka-magica

In *Puella Magi Madoka Magica*, if someone wishes something to Kyubey, they will become a magical girl (and in the end, a witch), but the wish can be anything like money, power, godlike powers. However, what would happen if they wish to ***not*** become a magical girl instead? (Perhaps only Madoka knows)

I was thinking if Kyubey would explode or refuse the wish, but what if he didn't refuse?

Comment: Possibly related: [Are all wishes actually possible?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9225)

Answer (score 5):

Kyubey gets these girls to sign a *contract*. This contract includes the provision that they become magical girls and fight witches (with the hidden eventuality that they will become witches themselves). Granting the wish is Kyubey's part of the contract. If someone does not agree to the contract in full, including the part about becoming a magical girl, why would Kyubey grant them a wish? In other words, not agreeing to become a magical girl in any way constitutes not agreeing to the terms, refusing the contract.

You must also remember that Kyubey intentionally offers the contract at specific moments when his target is most likely not to refuse. This is exemplified in Mami's case, explained in the [Puella Magi Wiki](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Mami_Tomoe#Mami_in_Farewell_Story):

> Mami made her wish after she was in a car accident with her parents. She was most likely very badly wounded, as her parents died on the scene, and Mami only survived due to making a wish with Kyubey, who appeared at just that moment, leaving Mami little time to consider her wish.

It's unlikely that Kuybey would approach someone at a time when they would either refuse to sign the contract, or who would in any other way *not* use the opportunity to wish for something important to them.

Comment: It's true that Kyubey is most likely cautious enough to avoid situations where the contractee would make such a wish. But an interesting thought experiment is: What would happen *if* Kyubey's measures failed and the contractee, perhaps out of an unforeseen moment of spite or whatever, made such a subversive wish?

Comment: @ahiijny It'd probably be up to him. This isn't some legally-binding contract, just a deal an alien offers.

Comment: The [circumstances around Madoka's wish](https://www.reddit.com/r/MadokaMagica/comments/47ik6n/why_didnt_kyubey_simply_turn_down_madokas_wish/) might imply that once the process starts, it's out of Kyubey's control.

Comment: @ahiijny Ah. Then likely the contract would be made null and void by not agreeing to become a magical girl, absolving Kyubey of the need to grant the wish.

Comment: @ahiijny that was my question, what would happen if he don't decline the wish.

Comment: @vegano I think we can only speculate on that. It's hinted that there are a number of rules that he must follow and which govern the wish-granting process, but he doesn't go into detail.

Answer (score 2):

**Kyubey is incapable of refusing a wish***, so if someone wishes to not become a magical girl then they won't. They'd deem this a waste of a perfectly good wish and would attempt to dissuade people from using it, since it would basically do nothing -- including not progressing the fight against entropy -- but if someone managed to wish "I want to not become a magical girl," then they would not become a magical girl and nothing would happen.

That said, the act of granting the wish seems to be what creates the Soul Gem (note Kyubey's wording: "What is the wish that will make your Soul Gem shine," (as the gem is forming) "Your wish has prevailed against entropy"). Therefore, it is possible that this wish could be used to create a "blank" gem, with no one inside it.

* *This isn't actually stated anywhere, but there's no other explanation, seeing as three distinct times across the franchise a wish has been granted that is, or seemed at the time to be, actively detrimental to Kyubey's goals (Madoka Kaname, Isabeau de Baviere, and Touka Satomi/Nemu Hiiragi/Ui Tamaki).*